# one and two dimensional Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral

> a) Evaluate the one-dimensional Gaussian integral
>
> $I(a)$ = $\int_R exp(-ax^2)dx$,  $a>0$
>
> b) evaluate the two-dimensional Gaussian integral using a)
>
> $I_2(a,b)$ = $\int_{R^2} exp(-ax^2  -by^2)dxdy, a,b>0$

For a) I have done the following:

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ $e^{-ax^2}dx = 2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx $

$I^2$ = 4$\int_0^\infty$$\int_0^\infty$$e^{-a(x^2 + y^2)}dydx$

...

$I^2$ = $\sqrt{\pi a}$

$I$ = $\pi$$\sqrt a$

I am having difficulties understanding how to solve b) any help or guide will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems backward, in the sense that part (b) should come first.  One of the standard elementary proofs of part (a) is to start with part (b), because the conversion to polar coordinates makes the integrand have an antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $e^{-ax^2-by^2} = e^{-a x^2}e^{-b y^2}$.

Then, note that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-ax^2-by^2} dy dx = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-a x^2}e^{-b y^2} dy dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-a x^2} dx \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-b y^2} dy$, and apply your result from part (a).

Also, note $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}} dx = 1$ (compare this to your answer for part (a)).

Answer (score 1):

Note the suggested answer in the original question is wrong. Should be:
$$I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

Comment: You may include relevant details of your argument that lead to this result. That would be more useful than a sentence written in minimal space... ;)

Comment: It's a standard result, just taking 10 seconds out of my day to avoid someone googling this and getting the wrong answer for their assignment.